# Simplest way to command 6DOF pose of a free object?

Tags: drake

I am trying to command the 6DOF pose of a tool directly during physics simulation, rather than relying on a robot to actuate the tool. The most obvious way I could think to do this is to add 3 prismatic joints, and 3 revolute joints to the plant, corresponding to each of the 6DOF I want to control. This, however, did not work.

This is what I tried for the x, Ry DOFs (and did similar for y, Ry, z, and Rz):

```
    screwdriver_x_joint = plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint(
            "screwdriver_x_joint",
            plant.world_frame(),
            plant.GetFrameByName("screwdriver_joint_frame"),
            axis=[1,0,0],
        )
    )
    plant.AddJointActuator("screwdriver_x_joint", screwdriver_x_joint)

    screwdriver_rx_joint = plant.AddJoint(
        RevoluteJoint(
            "screwdriver_rx_joint",
            plant.world_frame(),
            plant.GetFrameByName("screwdriver_joint_frame"),
            axis=[1,0,0],
        )
    )
    plant.AddJointActuator("screwdriver_rx_joint", screwdriver_rx_joint)
```

The error I got was:

```
This MultibodyGraph already has a joint 'screwdriver_x_joint' connecting 'world' to 'screwdriver'. Therefore adding joint 'screwdriver_rx_joint' connecting 'world' to 'screwdriver' is not allowed.
```

I saw in the answer to a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477852/how-to-add-jointactuator-for-planarjoint) that one option is to add additional "false" bodies, which are essentially just frames, then attach actuators to those bodies. But that seems quite convoluted; is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add (zero-mass) bodies in-between the joints. Here is some code that can do the job:

```
def AddFloatingRpyJoint(plant, frame, instance, use_ball_rpy=True):
    inertia = SpatialInertia(
        mass=0, p_PScm_E=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], G_SP_E=UnitInertia(0, 0, 0)
    )
    x_body = plant.AddRigidBody("x", instance, inertia)
    plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint(
            "x", plant.world_frame(), x_body.body_frame(), [1, 0, 0]
        )
    )
    y_body = plant.AddRigidBody("y", instance, inertia)
    plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint(
            "y", x_body.body_frame(), y_body.body_frame(), [0, 1, 0]
        )
    )
    z_body = plant.AddRigidBody("z", instance, inertia)
    plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint(
            "z", y_body.body_frame(), z_body.body_frame(), [0, 0, 1]
        )
    )
    if use_ball_rpy:
        plant.AddJoint(BallRpyJoint("ball", z_body.body_frame(), frame))
    else:
        # RollPitchYaw is body z-y-x
        rz_body = plant.AddRigidBody("rz", instance, inertia)
        plant.AddJoint(
            RevoluteJoint(
                "rz", z_body.body_frame(), rz_body.body_frame(), [0, 0, 1]
            )
        )
        ry_body = plant.AddRigidBody("ry", instance, inertia)
        plant.AddJoint(
            RevoluteJoint(
                "ry", rz_body.body_frame(), ry_body.body_frame(), [0, 1, 0]
            )
        )
        plant.AddJoint(
            RevoluteJoint("rx", ry_body.body_frame(), frame, [1, 0, 0])
        )
```

You can add the actuators in here, too.